# Angular reactive forms storing data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have worked with template driven forms before and I am slightly confused how the reactive forms work to store the data to my database. Initially I would just use **[(ngModel)]="user.date"**. How do I store the data now on submit? I have built one as follows:

```
this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
    this._formBuilder.group({
      dateFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
    this._formBuilder.group({
      emailFormCtrl: ['', Validators.email]
    }),
  ])
});
```

Here's an example of an input that I want to store to the db:

```
<input formControlName="dateFormCtrl" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" placeholder="When is your event?"(click)="picker.open()" readonly>
```

ATM I have this function which I built for the template driven form to store data:

```
 create() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user', this.user).subscribe(res => { ............
```

Answer (score 2):

your form should be like

```
 this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
       dateFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
       emailFormCtrl: ['', Validators.email]
    });
```

Your submit method should be like

```
   onSubmit(): void{
       const formObj ={
        date: this.form.value.dateFormCtrl,
        email: this.form.value.emailFormCtrl,
       }
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user', formObj).subscribe(res =>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save form data to a server dynamically, then you can follow the below code. It is the best available option.

In your component.ts file:

```
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';

    onSubmit() {
        this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);

        this.serverService.storeServers(this.payLoad)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => console.log(response),
          (error) => console.log(error)
        );

      }
```

In your service.ts file:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  storeServers(payLoad: any) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    return  this.http.post(' ***Complete URL*** ', payLoad, httpOptions);
  }
```